# AngularJS filtering using external JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, html-table, filtering, angularjs-filter

I've been wondering for some long time, how can I filter something like this. Here is my situation:

I have one JSON table like this:

```
var cars = [{
"id": 1,
"brand": "Ford",
"model": "Focus",
"generation": "2.0TDCi",
"version": "hatchback, 3 drzwi",
"mileage": 100,},{
"id": 2,
"brand": "Volkswagen",
"model": "Golf",
"generation": "III",
"version": " 1.9 TDI, hatchback, 4 drzwi",
"mileage": 14,}];
```

And I'm using this kind of generating table using data from JSON:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="car in cars" (...)
```

I've also have a dropdown with multiselection:

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="exampleBrand" selected-model="exampleBrandModel" extra-settings="exampleSettings"></div>
```

Things which are imported into this selector are from JSON file:

```
$scope.exampleBrand = [{id: 1, label: "Ford"}, {id: 2, label: "Ferrari"}, {id: 3, label:"Suzuki"},
                     {id: 4, label:"Fiat"}, {id: 5, label:"Aston Martin"}, {id: 6, label:"Opel"}];
```

The model of thing which are selected lands here:

```
$scope.exampleBrandModel = [];
```

For example if I select "Ford", the JSON file with model looks like this (checked with

> ```
> {{ exampleBrandModel| json }}
> ```

):

```
   [
  {
    "id": "Ford"
  }
]
```

And my question is. How can I use angular's filter option to make it working?
I was using something like that which was not working:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="car in cars |filter: {exampleBrandModel : id}">
```

I want to have situation like this:

At start I get whole table with cars listed in and then I select "Ford". Now every row in table without "Ford" word should be filtered out.

Do someone know how can I do that?

Comment: How big is your cars array? This doesn't directly answer your question, but angular filters can be slow (they are re-evaluated on ever digest), so for large ng-repeats, I recommend you do something like 

    displayedCars = cars.filter(function(car){ return car.name.match(/ford/)});

Comment: It might be up to 1000 car instances. Also it's some kind of a must-have to have this table (it'll have paging supported by front-end) been filtered by filter based on another JSON. That's why I've been asking about this issue which I encountered.